# Absolute position height 100% won't work on IE 11 - But it does on Microsoft Edge

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

Somehow IE 11 is missing my absoluted positioned element within another element with `height:100%`. It only seems to work if I give it a fixed height. (even though the parent's parent has a fixed one)

HTML

```
  <div class="parent-table">
    <div class="parent-cell">
      <div class="child">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%
}
.parent-table {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
}

.parent-cell {
  height: 300px;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  display: table-cell;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  width: 100%
}
```

[Reproduction Online JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/efvLdmtt/5/)

- IE Edge will show a red box (working as expected)
- IE 11 will show a blue box (totally missing the absoluted positioned element)

Comment: I assume you mean Microsoft Edge - "IE Edge" refers to something else that's basically identical to IE11. Microsoft Edge *is not IE*.

Comment: Yeah, Microsoft Edge

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This bug has been bugging lots of people forever. Internet explorer needs an intermediate element (now using `child` class) inside the cell before using an absolute positioned element (now using an `inner-child` class) inside of it as follows:

```
<div class="child">
  <div class="inner-child">
  </div>
</div>
```

The intermediate element should be styled as follows:

```
.child {
  display:inline-block;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:relative;
}
```

Here is the fiddle with the working solution on IE11 - but works on previous versions as well.

https://jsfiddle.net/efvLdmtt/7/

Comment: So it requires an `inline-block` element as a parent? Even when using a fixed height in a `display: table-cell` ?

Comment: Unfortunately yes

Answer (score 0):

**Apply overflow hidden to the parent element and bottom : -100% to the child element which is position absolute.**

*In my case it was a :pseudo element.*

***The Issue on IE*** --> 
[Click to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNQun.png)

***After the Fix*** -->
[Click to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/siaut.png)

```
.contact-box-parent {
   display: table-cell;
   overflow: hidden;
     &:before {
       content: '';
       background: @white;
       position: absolute;
       top: 0;
       bottom: -100%; 
       left: 15px;
       right: 15px;
       z-index: 0;
     }
  }
```

Comment: You just extended the background and hid the overflow content... this is unuseable for borders etc.